# Good Hiking Route Planner

Tags: hiking

I'm planning on hiking from John O'Groats in Scotland to Land's End in Cornwall via the Three Peaks. I'm wondering if there are any good online hiking planners that let you set waypoints and minimise the amount of time spent on roads whilst maximising the time spent on long-distance trails.

Mainly because planning a 1200+ mile route from scratch is a bit of a long-shot, I'd at least like something to start with.

Comment: I don't know about such a planner, but I think planning "manually" would definitely be worth it, as you will learn essential information about your route that way. Otherwise you'd have to get that information anyway after.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything that will do this for you, but the simple answer is to join up some well established paths, For example the [pennine bridle way](http://www.nationaltrail.co.uk/pennine-bridleway) is 205 miles straight down the centre of the country, if you join this up to the [offas dyke path](http://www.nationaltrail.co.uk/offas-dyke-path) then that's another 177 miles.

I'd also utilise the [canal network](https://www.waterways.org.uk/pdf/wwwaterwaysmap). This I know joins the offas dyke at Llangollen so that's those two joined up.

Basically a bit of simple research for long distance paths should do all this with minimal effort

Comment: In my experience this is not a trivial task. I find that last line of your answer a bit misleading; at best. :-)

Comment: But I've just done 400+ miles in a matter of minutes. That's probably about a 1/4 of the way.

Comment: Walking the 400+ miles and planning them in 2 minutes are drastically different. One should try to avoid rerouting and supply issues prior to the trip and that usually requires a fair amount of effort.